# Cчитать значение тега Текст на странице *.aspx.cs

Tags: asp.net, html, javascript

Здравствуйте. На странице `XML` я записываю в тег

```
<p contentEditable="true">Текст</p>
```

E-mail. Мне нужно считать этот `email` на странице `*.aspx.cs`, чтобы потом записать его в бд. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать. Хотела использовать строку

```
var str = Request.Form.GetValues("name");
```

но у тега `<p></p>` нет атрибута `name`. Как это можно сделать другим способом?
На стороне сервера у меня нет возможности это прописать, так как в программе данные должны записываться по определенному алгоритму, что лучше всего осуществить на `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

немного не понятно.. У вас есть внешний файл XML с неким набором тегов, который необходимо открыть и прочитать определенное содержимое для последующей записи в БД ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
 <p contentEditable="true">e@aaaa.com</p>
</root>

using System.Xml;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
    XmlNode n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("p[@contentEditable='true']");
    Response.Write("Содержимое : " + n.InnerText);
....
// запись в БД
```

Можно почитать про [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) запросы, с помощью которых очень легко сделать выборку необходимых элементов из XML файла

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь! Мне нужно записывать на страницу *.ascx!!!!